# How to stop endAt when it tries to search again from the end?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck when using endAt() in Firebase RealtimeDatabase.Some incorrect values appear in my results. Here is my code:

```
  resuftObj = await messagesRef
          .child("test")
          .orderByChild("country")
          .endAt("ja", "9")
          .limitToLast(4)
          .once("value");
```

Here my example data or view:
|-test:
|---1:{
"country" : "us",
"id" : 1
},
|---2:{
"country" : "ja",
"id" : 2
},
|---3:{
"country" : "ca",
"id" : 3
},
|---4:{
"country" : "uk",
"id" : 4
},
|---5:{
"country" : "us",
"id" : 5
},
|---6:{
"country" : "ca",
"id" : 6
},
|---7:{
"country" : "uk",
"id" : 7
},
|---8:{
"country" : "ja",
"id" : 8
},
|---9:{
"country" : "us",
"id" : 9
}

[image]

I would expect returned objects with "country" = "ja." But I see two values 3 and 6 ("country" = "ca"). My thinking is that when it reaches id= 2, my Query finds no more results so re-search from the end (id=9). How to prevent this?
Result:

```
{
    "2": {
        "country": "ja",
        "id": 2
    },
    "3": {
        "country": "ca",
        "id": 3
    },
    "6": {
        "country": "ca",
        "id": 6
    },
    "8": {
        "country": "ja",
        "id": 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further limit the results to only those with `country` equal to `ja`, you must also specify `startAt("ja")`:

```
ref.orderByChild("country")
          .startAt("ja")
          .endAt("ja", "9")
          .limitToLast(4)
```

Also see my repro here: https://jsbin.com/fajegol/edit?js,console

*Update*: it is easier to see why you're getting the `ca` results of you print the results in the right order (which I didn't do initially):

```
ref.orderByChild("country")
          .endAt("ja", "8")
          .limitToLast(4)
.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.val());
  })
});
```

Gives this output:

> { "country" : "ca", "id" : 3 }
>
> { "country" : "ca", "id" : 6 }
>
> { "country" : "ja", "id" : 2 }
>
> { "country" : "ja", "id" : 8 }

With that it makes a lot more sense: the child nodes are ordered on `country` and this is the last 4 nodes before the one you told it to `endAt()`.

The output in your question comes from logging `snapshot.val()`, which gives you the results without the order you requested (since keys in JSON are unordered by definition).

Comment: Thank you. You did this easily and correctly!